# Creating a table with an array field

Tags: sql, arrays, sqlite, sqldatatypes

Can someone explain to me how arrays work in SQLite?

I've tried: `CREATE TABLE foo (bar ARRAY);`

Works without errors but: `INSERT INTO foo VALUES ([1,2]);`
doesn't.

Note: The array can have any number of elements, element number is not limited.

Comment: Please note that `CREATE TABLE foo (bar FLUFFY BUNNIES);` works too …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite3 does not support arrays directly. Here are all types which are supported in SQLLite -> http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html.

To accomplish what you need, you have to use a custom encoding (JSON for example), or use an FK, i.e. create another table, where each item in the array is stored as a row.